# Deploying a Django Project through Git to Heroku: "No module named.. - failure"

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-bootstrap3

I'm hoping you may be able to help me and at the same time, I hope this query may serve others here well in the future.

Based on the excellent book: Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes, I am trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku with the use of Git and have come across several issues. Do note, there are some corrections to the book here: https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/updates.html

I am specifically mentioning the book here, as I believe it to be ranked one of the best starter books on various sites, so I can imagine other people facing the same problems - also, as there are several posts related to these 3 topics.

Initially, the app could be commited to Git, but then not pushed to Heroku using:

> `git push heroku master`

Part 1:
This contineously brought about the error:

```
No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See heroku local --help
```

To resolve this, it was vital to make sure the file had no extension (mac os) did not show it, but an ls in the directory showed the .txt ending on the file.

Part 2:
Retrying this, now allowed for a new message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'bootstrap3"
```

This could be resolved by making sure the django-bootstrap3==6.x.x requirement was available in the requirements.txt file when the command:

> pip freeze > requirements.txt

was issued - manually adding it did not do the trick.
In addition, I manually added:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
```

Next, I followed the instructions on an website instructing on how to disable collect static:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

This combination has gotten me a step further.

Part 3
All this done, I was now able to succesfully run the code:

> git push heroku master

However, running:

> heroku ps

directly afterwards, shows a crash

> web.1: crashed 2018/12/09 11:24:35 +0100 (~ 42m ago)

trying to migrate the database using the below command:

> heroku run python manage.py migrate

now let's me know, it is missing the module: dj-database-url

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'

Looking at my requirements.txt file though, I clearly have this in the list here.

Since the primary references in the net are either to check it is included in the requirements.txt file, the gunicorn file is defined correctly or collectstatic is disabled - I am at a loss and I hope someone might be able to help with this as well as hoping, the above pointers will benefit others dealing with the same early problems.

My files look as follows:

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn learning_log.wsgi —-log-file -
```

Procfile is with a capital "P" and the application is called learning_log

requirements.txt

```
astroid==2.1.0
autopep8==1.4.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.1.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
isort==4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pylint==2.2.2
pytz==2018.7
six==1.11.0
static3==0.7.0
wrapt==1.10.11
django-bootstrap3==6.2.2
psycopg2>=2.6.1
appdirs==1.4.3
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "learning_log.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

snip from the settings.py-file:

```
# Settings for django-bootstrap3
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

# Heroku Settings
cwd = os.getcwd()
print("--- CWD ---\n", cwd, "\n---\n")
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure().
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    # Allow all host headers.
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    # Static asset configuration
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

runtime.txt

> python-3.7.0

I sincerely hope, someone may be able to help here - I'm at a bit of a loss as to what else may be required.

I hope this is sufficient to explain - I understand that apparently there were also some updates on Heroku's side, but to learn this is really difficult.

Many thanks,
Simon

Comment: I don't see `whitenoise` in your *requirements.txt*. Have you committed all of the changes you made each time you push to heroku?

Comment: @japhyr - unfortunately yes it is - i must have picked an old export before running a freeze again.
It includes: whitenoise==4.1.2

I commited all files at the end - not every time I'm afraid, as I was only learning this and only then learnt what this meant.

Comment: To be on the safe side - have recommited everything to be on the safe side. Commit works, but migrate then fails - still with the error message: dj_database_url not found which is part of the requirements file as: dj-database-url. (Hyphen instead of underscore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after lot's and lot's of testing - I finally realized that the requirement file kept changing (I am pretty certain, not only when I ran freeze).

As a result, several packages previously installed were no longer in the requirements.txt file. Essentially this means, this error really was down to the requirements.txt file beeing complete and having ALL required packages in it.

My final package list was as follows:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
astroid==2.0.4
certifi==2018.8.24
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
Django==2.1.1
django-bootstrap3==11.0.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
gunicorn==19.3.0
idna==2.7
isort==4.3.4
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
matplotlib==2.2.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.15.0
psycopg2>=2.6.1
pygal==2.4.0
pygal-maps-world==1.0.2
pygame==1.9.4
pylint==2.1.1
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
six==1.11.0
static3==0.6.1
urllib3==1.23
virtualenv==16.0.0
whitenoise==4.1.2
wrapt==1.10.11
```

Comment: That's great, I'm glad you got this sorted out! (I'm the author of PCC.)